# SQL - How to filter against multiple rows in joined table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `Students` and a table called `Courses` and a table `Student_Course` which creates a many-to-many relationship between the two via a `student_id` foreign key and `course_id` foreign key.

I am attempting to query for students and filter the results to include only those who have taken both the "Math" AND "Science" courses.

This seems like it should be a fairly simple task, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Show your table definitions and your SELECT code, don't describe it. It makes it much harder for people to understand what you are describing

Comment: @Barmar, I believe this question is significantly different from the one you marked as a duplicate. Would you please reopen?

Comment: What's the significant difference? Because you're joining tables? Just join with a subquery that uses one of the answers in that question.

Comment: @Barmar, yes the joining. The solutions may be similar, but to beginners viewing these questions, they're different enough. If I had come across that question in my original search I would not have made the connection between it and my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the most simple solution is

```
 select s.*
 from Student s
 join Student_Course sc on s.student_id = sc.student_id
 join Courses c on sc.course_id = c.course_id 
 where c.name in ('math', 'science')
 group by sc.student_id
 having count(distinct c.course_id) = 2
```

The `distinct` is not necessary if the student can not attend the same course many times. Another solution is to use `EXISTS` as follows

```
 select *
 from Student s
 where exists (
   select 1
   from Student_Course sc
   join Courses c on sc.course_id = c.course_id 
   where s.student_id = sc.student_id and c.name = 'math'
 ) and exists (
   select 1
   from Student_Course sc
   join Courses c on sc.course_id = c.course_id 
   where s.student_id = sc.student_id and c.name = 'science'
 )
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I didn't end up needing to use DISTINCT or the nested query solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sum` you can get the required data as

```
select s.*
from Students s
join Student_Course sc on s.id = sc.student_id
join courses c on c.id = sc.course_id
group by s.id
having sum(c.name = 'Math')
and sum(c.name = 'Science')
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me also, but I went with Radim's answer because I am less sure _how_ this one works.

Answer (score 0):

working fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71e36b/1

// select

```
select
 a.student_name,
 c.course_name
from
  Students a
  inner join Student_Course b on a.student_id = b.student_id
  inner join Courses c on b.course_id = c.course_id
 where
   c.course_name = 'Math' OR c.course_name = 'Science'
```

// schema

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
  student_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  student_name varchar(200) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Courses (
  course_id  int(11) NOT NULL,
  course_name varchar(200) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Student_Course   (
  student_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  course_id  int(11) NOT NULL
);

insert into Students (student_id, student_name) values (1, 'mike');
insert into Students (student_id, student_name) values (2, 'eugene');
insert into Students (student_id, student_name) values (3, 'paul');

insert into Courses (course_id, course_name) values(1, 'Math');
insert into Courses (course_id, course_name) values(2, 'Phys');
insert into Courses (course_id, course_name) values(3, 'Chemistry');
insert into Courses (course_id, course_name) values(4, 'Language');
insert into Courses (course_id, course_name) values(5, 'Science');

insert into Student_Course(student_id, course_id) values(1, 1);
insert into Student_Course(student_id, course_id) values(1, 2);
insert into Student_Course(student_id, course_id) values(1, 3);
insert into Student_Course(student_id, course_id) values(2, 1);
insert into Student_Course(student_id, course_id) values(3, 5);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it needs to be **AND**. I need students who have taken both.